# Is DateString supposed to be truncating seconds?

Tags: date-and-time

If I configure `DateString` to format dates as ISO dates with

```
$DateStringFormat := {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", ":", 
      "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "SecondExact", 
      If[$TimeZone == 0, "Z", "UTC" <> ToString[$TimeZone]]}
```

I get truncated seconds, rather than rounded seconds

```
{2012, 10, 12, 21, 32, 22.5359} // DateString
2012-10-12T:21:32:22.535UTC-5.
```

This seems wrong. The result should either be

```
2012-10-12T:21:32:22.5359UTC-5.
```

or

```
2012-10-12T:21:32:22.536UTC-5.
```

Is it a bug, or am I misunderstanding `"SecondExact"` or `DateString`?

Comment: Looks like it only supports a maximum of three decimal places in "Millisecond".

Comment: What the OP is complaining about is caused by simple mistake. `DateString` only handles time to down to the millisecond level. Therefore, putting 22.5359 into the seconds slot of a date list, which is asking for time at the 100 microsecond level, is just not going to work. Not surprising that DateString truncates it.

Comment: I believe this is documented: *With a typical value for $DateStringFormat, DateString[{y, m, d, h, m, s}] will truncate fractional seconds.*

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries but, OP is explicitly specifying `"SecondExact"` as part of the format, which supposedly represents "seconds including fractions". m_goldberg is right that `DateString` truncates these values, but it isn't really documented as such, there seems to be no good reason for it, and it certainly isn't OP's mistake. I would call it a bug.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Yes, that's my question. The documentation is hardly clear. The way I read it, it was describing the purpose of "SecondExact", by showing what happened if one used a "typical" format instead. If instead of "a typical value" they mean "all values", they should say so (and explain that "SecondExact" doesn't really do anything).

Comment: @OleksandrR. I may have misread that line. In the context of this question I interpreted that to mean that DateString may slash of *some* digits of the fraction, but that was probably reading too much in it. The author of that line probably meant to say "truncate to whole seconds".

Comment: Anyway, you could use `Round[seconds,0.001]`

Comment: @OleksandrR. I don't think it's a bug. The documentation clearly states the "Milliseconds" only gives three digits. I don't see "SecondExact" giving more precision than that. It is essentially `Seconds + Milliseconds/100`. I would agree that the name "SecondExact" is a bad choice for the format in question.

Comment: @m_goldberg: So it sounds like an answer is developing: DateString truncates, despite the poorly named "SecondExact", and documentation that implies that there is some not "typical" way to avoid the truncation.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are misunderstanding `"SecondExact"`. Consider

```
Column[{
   DateString[DateList[], {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}],
   DateString[DateList[], {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "SecondExact"}]}]
```

> ```
> 12:02:48.748
> 12:02:48.748
> ```

This shows that `"SecondExact"` is just a shortcut for `"Second", ".", "Millisecond"`. The documentation for [`DateString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateString.html) clearly states that `"Millisecond"` is only given to three digits. Therefore, giving seconds to more than 3 decimal place in a `DataList` isn't going produce any additional precision in the output from `DateString`. As to why `DateString` truncates, I would say that was a WRI developer's decision.

Comment: What does "typical" in the documentation mean? What is not "typical"?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. Where in the docs is the "typical" are you referring to?

Comment: The comment above from @SjoerdC.deVries.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius. Ok. I've found the "typical".  I don't think that doc item is relevant to your question. It refers to truncating time to whole seconds. The reasoning behind it, I would guess, is to make date strings look more like a digital clock displays. Clocks don't round seconds, they truncate them. Maybe the same readoning was applied to "Milliseconds", but who's to say?

Comment: Yet `DateList` is perfectly happy to give the time to the nearest 100ns as reported by the system clock: `DateList[] -> {2014, 1, 8, 19, 55, 13.7832844}`. If not a bug, it definitely seems like a stupid design decision to make `DateString` arbitrarily truncate in this way.